# Ultra Sound Gender Prediction Accuray

Tags: medical-imaging, radiology, ultrasounds, gender-sex-identity

Sorry for a very basic Question (as I am a software engineer) but I am confused after getting material from internet about accuracy of Ultra Sound Gender prediction

**Question**: How much this is likely that a pregnant lady is carrying baby boy if she is told that this is a girl (by an experienced sonographer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetal gender determination is suprisingly accurate, according to this study: [Accuracy of sonographic fetal gender determination: predictions made by sonographers during routine obstetric ultrasound scans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5024945/)

The results state the following:

> Results confirmed 100% accuracy in predictions made after 14 weeks
> gestation. The overall success rate in the first trimester group
> (11–14 weeks) was 75%. When excluding those scans where a prediction
> could not be made, success rates increased to 91%.
>
> Results were less accurate for fetuses younger than 12 weeks, with an overall success
> rate of 54%. Male fetuses under 13 weeks were more likely to have
> gender incorrectly or unable to be assigned. After 13 weeks, success
> rates for correctly predicting males exceeded that of female fetuses.
>
> Statistical differences were noted in the success rates of individual
> sonographers.

Provided the scan is done after 14 weeks, accuracy is very good, but can vary between sonographers.

Currently in the [UK antenatal care schedule](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/pregnancy-and-baby/antenatal-appointment-schedule/), most women will have an initial scan at 8-14 weeks and then an anomaly scan at 18-20 weeks gestation.